# Oracle Global Temporary Tables and using stored procedures and functions

Tags: oracle10g

we recently changed one of the databases I develop on from Oracle accounts to LDAP login accounts and all went well for the front end used by the staff that access the system.  However, we have a second method of entry restricted to admin staff that load the data onto the database and a lot of processing is called using the dbms_scheduler.

Most of the database tables have a created_by column which is defaulted to pick up their user name from a sys_context but when the data loads are run from dbms_scheduler this information is not available and hence the created_by columns all get populated with APP_GLOBAL.

I have managed to populate a Global Temporary Table (GTT) with the sys_context value and use this to populate the created_by from a stored procedure called by dbms_scheduler so my next logical step was to put this in a function and call it so it could be used throughout the system or even be referenced from a before insert trigger.

The problem is, when putting the code into a function the data from the GTT is not found.  The table is set to preserve rows.

I have trawled many a site for an answer but have found nothing to help me can anyone here provide a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The scheduler will be using a different session than the session that created the job - `preserve rows` will not make the GTT data visible in a different session.

I am assuming the `created_by` columns have a default value like `nvl(sys_context(...),'APP_GLOBAL')`. Consider passing the user name as a parameter to the job and set the context as the first step in the job.

Comment: Jack, I have managed to populate the GTT for the same session as the dbms_scheduler and can select from it.  I put the code into a function so it could be referenced by all stored procedures run from the scheduler but when referencing the function no data from the GTT is returned.  Your assumption about created_by is almost correct, the expression is the column's default value and not in a trigger.

Comment: @Colin sorry - the reference to triggers was a typo

Comment: @Colin the scheduler will use a different session for each job it runs

Answer (score 0):

A weekend off and a closer look at my code showed a fatal flaw in my syntax where the selection of data from the GTT would never happen.  A quick tweak and recompile and all is well.

Jack, thanks for your help.